# Argument Type (WCHAR*) is incompatible with parameter of type "const char*)

Tags: c++, winapi, wchar

This is part of some CSGO code and I don't know how to fix this problem; It's on line 8 of the snippet shown below:

[image]

```
uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(const char* modName) {
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry)) {
            do {
                if (!strcmp(modEntry.szModule, modName)) {
                    CloseHandle(hSnap);
                    return (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Argument Type (WCHAR*) is incompatible with parameter of type "const char*)
```

Comment: Change your project settings to multibyte instead of unicode.

Comment: Read about `TCHAR` and use the corresponding functions; `_tcscmp`, in your case.

Comment: @zdf But then the whole function (or even codebase) would have to be changed. Note that the given function takes a `const char*` argument.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, you are right, but `TCHAR` is the right way. Otherwise you’ll have to manually take care of conversions and/or narrow/wide functions; eg `GetModuleFileNameA` - notice the ending `A`.

Comment: @zdf I would agree that using `TCHAR` is the *preferred* way but what is right/wrong depends on the nature of the OP's code base, and how deeply 'embedded' the hard-coded use of `char` types is. Unfortunately, the structures and functions in the `TlHelp32.h` header aren't as cleanly defined (in terms of the `A` or `W` suffixes) as other WINAPI stuff.

Comment: `TCHAR` is not the preferred way and has not been for more than a decade. There's no need to support Win98 any more.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think `TCHAR` is used in *many* real-world applications that run on OSes newer than Windows 98.  But my point was really addressing the comment(s) made by zdf.

Comment: @adrian I am sure it is used in many applications. I don't dispute that. It's just not the preferred way which is what you stated.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, your problem lies in the fact that your (new) project has the "Use Unicode Character Set" option set for builds but the (old) code base expects to be built using the "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" option. (The former uses the `wchar_t*` type for strings in Windows API calls and structures, whereas the latter uses the `char*` type; these are incompatible pointers.)

So, the 'quick fix' is to set your project's build options to use the "Multi-Byte" character set. In Visual Studio 2019, this option is the project's **Properties -> Advanced -> Character Set** when you right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer; earlier versions of Visual Studio have the option in the **General** property tab, IIRC.

If you are using some other IDE, then you'll need to 'manually' undefine the `UNICODE` macro (which signals to the compiler that the "Unicode Character Set" is in use); an `#undef UNICODE` line ***before*** any of your `#include <...>` lines for the system headers would work.

For much (most) of the Windows API, this issue can also be resolved by using explicit `wchar_t` or `char` versions of structures and functions; for example, the `GetModuleFileName` function, mentioned in the comments, resolves to either `GetModuleFileNameW` or `GetModuleFileNameA`, depending on which character set is chosen for the build, and structures used in those calls have `W` and `A` versions defined explicitly. Thus, one can 'override' the default call for the project's setting by explicitly using the `A`- or `W`-suffixed versions of those functions and structures.

However, in your particular case, unfortunately, the `TlHelp32.h` header file (and the functions it defines) are not so well defined: There are no *explicit* `A`-suffixed versions, so you can't simply suffix your `MODULEENTRY32` and `Module32First` references with an `A`, as one would like. (For Unicode builds, the `W`-suffixed versions simply overwrite the 'original' function and structure names, so these are then lost to your code.)

Thus, without changing your code to use `TCHAR` types throughout (`TCHAR` resolves to either `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on the character set option), your only sensible option is the aforementioned quick fix: change the build settings.